# Match cells from Worksheet to column in Summary Sheet / VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to parse through many different sheets and pick out specific data. I then need to place this data into specific columns and rows that depend on which column and row they are in the original sheet. In order to determine the row I need to create a range that contains the column all the way down to the current cell. I found code that explains how to do that ([Select from ActiveCell to first cell in column. Data in column includes blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450321/select-from-activecell-to-first-cell-in-column-data-in-column-includes-blanks)), but when I run it, it throws the error message "Method "Range" not supported for Object "Worksheet"". I have already tried removing xSheet before the Range statement. Is there maybe something else wrong with my code? Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

```
Dim xSheet As Worksheet, DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long, crow As Long, ccol As Long
Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range, colSrc As Range, rowSrc As Range
Dim cRange As Range, copyTemp As Range, copyEnd As Range, copyStart As Range
Dim exchDest As Range, rowRange As Range
Dim numCol As Long, numRow As Long
Dim c As Range, q As Range
Dim uniqueVal() As Variant, x As Long

For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Edit 
        Set copyStart = xSheet.Range("A1")
        crow = xSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ccol = xSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column 'find a smarter way of doing this
        Set copyEnd = xSheet.Cells(crow, ccol)
        Set copyRng = xSheet.Range(copyStart, copyEnd)    

    If InStr(1, xSheet.Name, "ACCOUNT") And xSheet.Range("B1") <> "No Summary Available" Then _

        For Each c In copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            If IsNumeric(c) And Not c.Value = "0" Then _

                Set rowRange = xSheet.Range(c.EntireColumn.Cells(1), c) 'problem line
                For Each q In rowRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    If InStr(1, q.Value, "C-") Then _
                        Set rowSrc = q
                    Next q

                Set colSrc = c.EntireRow.Offset(0).Cells(1)
                numCol = DestSh.Cells.Find(colSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                numRow = DestSh.Cells.Find(rowSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

                'Set destination
                Set destRng = DestSh.Cells(numRow, numCol)

                'Copy to destination Range
                c.Copy destRng



                'If destRng.Column > 40 Then _
                '   Set destRng = destRng.Offset(1, -30)


            End If

        Next c

    End If

Next xSheet
```

Comment: Could you add the variable definitions please.

Comment: @UGB yes of course!

Comment: `copyRng` is not set to a range.

Comment: @TimWilliams doesn't "Dim copyRng As Range" set copyRng as range or is that not how it works? I also don't have any problems with copyRng in the other for loops that I am using.

Comment: Declaring the variable with Dim just tells the runtime that there's a variable of type Range: it doesn't assign that variable to any particular range.  You would do that using (eg) `Set copyRng = xSheet.Range("A1")`

Comment: Your code should never even reach the line you say is giving the error, since it should bomb out at `For Each c In copyRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` with "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @TimWilliams you are right. I have copyRng Set as range earlier in my code. Sorry for the confusion. I was hesitant on posting it since it is quite long and I still have a long ways to go to make it neat.

Comment: Is `copyRng` pointing to the same worksheet as `xSheet` ?  You can'r reference a range from xSheet using two ranges from a different sheet.

Comment: Yes that seems to have been an issue, I fixed it (see edit) and now it is at least not throwing an error at that line anymore. I am now working through issues with rowSrc and colSrc since they need to be Set as well. In particular rowSrc seems to be an issue when I reach the line numRow = DestSh.Cells.Find(rowSrc.Value, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row which tells me it has never been set.

Comment: When using Find it's best to check the return value is not `Nothing` *before* trying to access its properties such as `Row`, `Column`